# Problem with centred X and O in Tictactoe 10*10 game

Tags: python, tkinter, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to make 10*10 tictactoe game but there is one problem. I do not know how I can make that X and O would be centered in each box.
Here is code:

```
import tkinter
p = tkinter.Canvas(width=500,height=550)
p.pack()
a=0
b=50
c=1
p.create_text(100, 10, text='Na rade je kruh',tags="kriz")
for i in range(10):
    p.create_line(a,50,a,550)
    a+=50
for i in range(10):
    p.create_line(0,b,500,b)
    b+=50
def kriz(sur):
    global k,l
    k=sur.x
    l=sur.y
    p.create_line(k-10,l+10,k+10,l-10,width=5,tags="m")
    p.create_line(k-10,l-10,k+10,l+10,width=5,tags="m")
def kruh(sur):
    global s,d
    s=sur.x
    d=sur.y
    p.create_oval(s-10,d-10,s+10,d+10,width=5,tags="l")
def tictactoe(sur):
    global c
    if c%2== 0:
       kriz(sur)
       p.create_text(100, 10, text='Na rade je kruh',tags="kriz")
       p.delete("kruh")
    else:
       kruh(sur)
       p.create_text(100, 10, text='Na rade je krížik',tags="kruh")
       p.delete("kriz")
    c+=1
def zmaz():
    p.delete("m")
    p.delete("l")
p.bind("<Button-1>", tictactoe)
button1 = tkinter.Button(text="reset", command=zmaz)
button1.pack()
root = tkinter.Tk()
tkinter.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

To center the X and O in their boxes you can use `int(sur.x/50)*50+25` and `int(sur.y/50)*50+25`. Below the full working code including the in your code missing bottom line:

```
import tkinter
p = tkinter.Canvas(width=500,height=550)
p.pack()
a=0
b=50
c=1
p.create_text(100, 10, text='Na rade je kruh',tags="kriz")
for i in range(10):
    p.create_line(a,50,a,550)
    a+=50
for i in range(11):
    p.create_line(0,b,500,b)
    b+=50
def kriz(sur):
    global k,l
    k=int(sur.x/50)*50+25
    l=int(sur.y/50)*50+25
    p.create_line(k-10,l+10,k+10,l-10,width=5,tags="m")
    p.create_line(k-10,l-10,k+10,l+10,width=5,tags="m")
def kruh(sur):
    global s,d
    s=int(sur.x/50)*50+25
    d=int(sur.y/50)*50+25
    p.create_oval(s-10,d-10,s+10,d+10,width=5,tags="l")
def tictactoe(sur):
    global c
    if c%2== 0:
       kriz(sur)
       p.create_text(100, 10, text='Na rade je kruh',tags="kriz")
       p.delete("kruh")
    else:
       kruh(sur)
       p.create_text(100, 10, text='Na rade je krížik',tags="kruh")
       p.delete("kriz")
    c+=1
def zmaz():
    p.delete("m")
    p.delete("l")
p.bind("<Button-1>", tictactoe)
button1 = tkinter.Button(text="reset", command=zmaz) 
button1.pack()

root = tkinter.Tk()
tkinter.mainloop()
```